# How enable "Individual column searching (select inputs)" in Jquery datatables?

Tags: jquery, datatables

i am trying achieve this [Individual column searching (select inputs)](https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html)

i am loading data to JqueryDatatable via ajax call.

but select dropdown for per column is not showing up.

my code is like below

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function () {

        $('#myTable').dataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "@Url.Action("GetAjaxData", "Home")",
            "bProcessing": true,
            "searching": false,
            "aoColumns": [
                    { "sName": "First Name" },
                    { "sName": "Last Name" },
                    { "sName": "Nationality" },
                    { "sName": "Date of Birth" }
            ],
            "initComplete": function () {
                this.api().columns().every(function () {
                    var column = this;
                    var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                      .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                      .on('change', function () {
                          var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                          );

                          column
                            .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                            .draw();
                      });

                    column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                        select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                    });
                });
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

what i am missing ?

Comment: You probably not have a `<tfoot>` section in your markup.

Comment: you can try my yadcf plugin for that, see showcase sample http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/server_side_source.html